# Adding shadow to inside of text field Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have this design that I'd like to use for my app but I'm not quite sure on how to add the box shadow. The shadow is on the inside of a TextField.. please can someone give me some assistance and point me in the right direction on how to do this?

[image: The design I'd like top replicate]

(the box shadow at the top of the TextField)

Cheers,
Jack

Comment: That's called neumorphic design. I'm not sure how to do that but there are articles like this out there: https://medium.com/flutter-community/neumorphic-designs-in-flutter-eab9a4de2059

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that using a container as a background, for example using a [Linear 
Gradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient-class.html) you can get something like this:

[image]

```
Container(
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFFe6dfd8), Color(0xFFf7f5ec)],
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0.0, 0.4],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
        ),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
      ),
      child: TextField(
          expands: false, 
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black54),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.email,
                color: Colors.black54,
              ),
              hintText: 'email',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              ),
              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
```

You can improve the effect using a [Radial Gradient](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/RadialGradient-class.html), a [Box Shadow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html) or as @Jakk said a Neumorphic shape.

Hope it helps.

Comment: breaks in error view