# How to create inner shadow in textfield Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create the text field which should look like this in the picture. As I understood it creates with inner shadow to reach such effect as on the pic. How can I recreate this? I was trying to write code like this, but it also doesn't look like as I would like.

[image]

The code I tried:

```
 Container(
                            width: 450,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.indigoAccent,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                        blurRadius: 2,
                                        spreadRadius: 2)
                                  ]),
                              width: double.infinity,
                              height: 20,
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text("Content goes here"),
                              ),
                            ))
```

Comment: REFER [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066259/adding-shadow-to-inside-of-text-field-flutter).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding shadow to inside of text field Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066259/adding-shadow-to-inside-of-text-field-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can try it:

> ```
> Container(
>       decoration: ShapeDecoration(
>         gradient: LinearGradient(
>           colors: [Color(0xFFe6dfd8), Color(0xFFf7f5ec)],
>           begin: Alignment.topCenter,
>           end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>           stops: [0.0, 0.4],
>           tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
>         ),
>         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
>           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
>         ),
>       ),
>       child: TextField(
>           expands: false, 
>             style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black54),
>             decoration: InputDecoration(
>               contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
>               prefixIcon: Icon(
>                 Icons.email,
>                 color: Colors.black54,
>               ),
>               hintText: 'email',
>               hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
>               focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
>                 borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
>                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
>               ),
>               enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
>                 borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
>                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
>               ),
>             ),
>           ),
>     );
> ```